# Strange behaviour of PHP script performing SELECT query

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, select

I've a PHP script that has been working well for a long time. It basically performs a query to a remote database; using postgreSQL API:

```
SELECT id,command FROM tablet_sync WHERE id>$certainNumber
```

Id field is a **int4** type; and command is a **text** type.

As I said, it has been working well for a long time. But recently, I found that sometimes the **command** field could be a little (but not extremly) large; about 10000 characters or more.

Well, when that query find a row wich its field **command** is larger than certain number of characters (about 9000); it does not work.

- Apache call never ends.
- No error message is noticed (PHP/Apache log files, client and server).

I should tell that if this query is performed in a PostgreSQL client, let's say, pgAdmin, it works perfectly (of course, 10000 bytes of data is not a large amount of data!).
But it does not work if I make it from my PHP script.

I give you all other information that could be usefull to solve the problem:

- Server and client have same Apache amd PHP versions: 2.2 , and 5.3.0; respectively.
- Client and server are NOT located in the same machine
- If I limit the amount of data to recover when perfmorming the query in PHP script file; **it works!**. (for ex: SELECT id,(**CAST command AS varchar(9000)** FROM tablet_sync WHERE id>$certainNumber)

****Updated****
I could figure that PostgreSQL remote database server is throwing these errors:

- LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out
- LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection

Despite these errors, PHP call still does not end...

****04/08 Updated****

Thank you for your answer @regilero. I've done some tests:

1. Changing timeout value has not worked in any way.
2. I've found, thanks to SHOW AL command, that some configuration fields are
   diferent in Client and Server side: **all locales (lc_collate,
   lc_message etc;);** are set in UTF-8 in server side, meanwhile in
   client side are set to English_United States.1252. **max_fsm_pages**
   is set to 153600; less than client side. I found that postgreSQL version are different too in client and server side: 8.3.1 and 8.3.9, respectively. **shared_buffer** value is set different too: 32MB and 24MB; client and server, respectively. No more relevant differences have been found.
3. I use [PHP API connector to PostgreSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php) and has been working well since now. PHP error log file is not showing anything.

Comment: How do you perform the query? By "PostgreSQL API" do you mean the pg_* functions?

Comment: Have you checked the MySQL error log too? A long shot...

Comment: I meant Postgres, freudian slip, was just answering a MySQL question.

Comment: @bertzzie; yes, i am using pg_* functions, and they have been worked well all since now. I've also checked PostgreSQL lof file; and no error are noticed. It only shows a connection error when I manually stop the call (I click stop button on firefox). I should also tell that PHP script which is called is located in client machine (localhost); but database is located in a remote server.

Comment: Can you try with more recent PHP version (5.3.8 perhaps)?

Comment: @Darhazer Hum.. I'll try it thank you. This project was stopped but now it started again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a timeout problem.

On the postgresql session side you can try to add theses commands before your query:

```
set statement_timeout to 10000;
```

It's a value in ms, you could also try to set it to 0 (infinite).

If it comes from a tcp problem on the session you could adjust theses 3 settings:

```
set tcp_keepalives_count to 10;
set tcp_keepalives_idle to 2;
set tcp_keepalives_interval to 1;
```

or other values (here is just a random try). Here it means, try to make a 'tcp keepalive ping' every 2s, retry every 1s if failed, and allow 10 retry before dying (0 means system's default).

Now the problem could also be on the client side, which postgresql connector do you use? What are the optioinnal settings use with this connection (connection string, default conf values,...). A "`SHOW ALL;`" will list every settings, you should try to perform this query from your PHP client and store the result somewhere, then examine every settings in this list, and check the difference with the same query from pgadmin.

Comment: I edited my question attaching some tests. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I do not understand the #2 in your edit, show all cannot show difference in client and server, it's just that you perform show all from different client, isn't it (pgadmin is a client, as php API)? but are you requesting 2 different servers? shared_buffer is a server setting, you cannot get 2 values for that config from different clients.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I did not tell that the system has TWO servers (one is client and server in the same machine, and there is another remote server). The reason is that sometimes client must work without Internet Connection; so it stores information in local database; and then tries to synchronize to remote server. So..yes...I permormed a 'SHOW ALL' from same client (pgAdmin) to different servers :/. So you're telling me to perform 'SHOW ALL' command from pgAdmin client and PHP API client, to the same remote server; and check for differences? Thanks.